# Why is it possible to call functions using slashes in iPython?

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

Today I encountered the possibility to call functions using a rather odd slash-syntax in the iPython console. It worked for me using iPython 2 and 3 on both Windows and Linux as well as in the Notebook but not in a regular Python console. An example of what I mean:

```
In [4]: def test():
...:        print 'hello'
In [5]: / test
hello
```

As I wrote, this works in the iPython-console but raises `SyntaxError` in the regular one. Is there any partical reason for this iPython-specific syntax of calling functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is simply one of the features of `ipython`. It exists to make it possible to call functions without using the parenthesis.

Starting your line with `/` tells it to treat the first word as a function name, add parenthesis to it, and treat any following words or symbols as arguments.

So, for example

```
/ str 42
```

Becomes interpreted as:

```
str(42)
```

You can find more explanation for this, and other features of `ipython` on [this page](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-autocall).

Comment: That's a feature that I had missed completely. To me it only makes function calls less explicit, but I guess it's a matter of taste.